# Why is my Julia HTTP.jl handler function throwing an error?

Tags: http, post, request, julia, microservices

I am trying to turn some Julia code into a very basic local microservice, which accepts a POST request with some options supplied via JSON, runs a program, and returns a 200 response. My microservice code is here:

```
const ROUTERS = Dict()

function __init__()
    """Initialisation function to populate the global variables."""
    ROUTERS["ROUTER"] = HTTP.Router()
    HTTP.register!(ROUTERS["ROUTER"], "POST", "/run", run_program)
end

function run_program(req)
    """Takes a run request and passes it to the main program, before sending a 200 reponse to say no errors have occured."""
    setup = JSON3.read(req.body, Dict{String, Any})
    run_program(setup) 
    return HTTP.Response(200, JSON3.write("Success."))
end

function requestHandler(req)
    """Recieves incoming requests and passes them to the router. Returns the response object."""
    local resp
    resp = HTTP.handle(ROUTERS["ROUTER"], req)
    return resp
end

function run_service(port=8080)
    """Runs the microservice at the specified port."""
    HTTP.serve(requestHandler, "0.0.0.0", port)
end

__init__()
```

This code works with HTTP version 0.9.17, but I updated it to the new version 1.5.5. Now I receive this error whenever I make a request to the running service:

```
 LogLevel(1999): handle_connection handler error
│   exception =
│    UndefVarError: handle not defined
```

What am I missing here? Have I defined my handler function incorrectly somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `HTTP.handle` function anymore in HTTP.jl version 1.x, as outlined by the [documentation](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/stable/#%22Handlers%22-framework-overhaul).

You'll probably want something like

```
"""
Receives incoming requests and passes them to the router. Returns the response object.
"""
function requestHandler(req)
    return ROUTERS["ROUTER"](req)
end
```

instead. Also note that docstrings need to be inserted before the function for the docsystem to pick them up.

Comment: We tried to include some documentation around this breaking change [here](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/stable/#%22Handlers%22-framework-overhaul).